# Multiple firebase environments in different regions

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am building a web application and need a dev instance and a prod instance. In the past I've always made two separate firebase projects (project-name-dev and project-name-prod) and used aliases to deploy to each environment.

I now have a need to host the same project in two different regions (US data needs to live in US, Canada data needs to live in Canada). I still need a dev and prod instance. My current thought is to create two new projects totaling 4 separate firebase backends that all use the same frontend

- project-name-us-dev
- project-name-us-prod
- project-name-ca-dev
- project-name-ca-prod

The front end code is using Vue.js. (not sure if that's relevant or not)

Is there a simpler way of managing this project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this question google-cloud-firestore, I'll assume that you are mostly referring to the location of the data in Firestore.  I suggest reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) if you haven't already.  Once you've chosen a region for Firestore, that project is locked into that location for the rest of its life, in addition to its default storage bucket as well as GAE.  Since you can't have two Firestore instances in the same project, and you have to choose a location for Firestore in the project, it stands to reason that there isn't any easier way to manage your projects than what you're doing now.